NID65 - R.C. and Trim pins
I'm planning to use the NID65-5 DC/DC converter. The datasheet mentions Pin 10 "Trim (optional)" and Pin 11 "R.C.":

What R.C. means? How should I connect these pins? There is no other information in the datasheet about them and the example circuit doesn't show them:

Additional note: In the "negative output voltage circuit", both of them appear to be not connected. Is R.C. a typo and it is supposed to be N.C.?

R.C. is listed in the specification on page 1 as Remote Control.

FUNCTION
REMOTE CONTROL
Power on : 1.2VDC < R.C ~ com < 12VDC or open circuit ; power off : R.C ~ com < 0.4VDC or short circuit (PIN5,6 & PIN11)

In English:

If the pin is driven by 1.2 V to 12 V or left open circuit the output will be powered on.
If the pin is pulled to less than 0.4 V the output power will be switched off.
If R.C. (pin 11) is connected to COM (pins 5 or 6) the output will be switched off. (This is really the same as the previous bullet point.)

The basic idea is that the chip's high-current output can be switched off with a small switch or low power transistor / microcontroller.
If you don't need the function you can leave the pin floating.

Thanks, I didn't notice it in the table! Any idea for the Trim? I can probably left it NC but I'm curious

No. An extensive web search revealed nothing. It's probably supposed to be connected to the wiper of a pot to allow precise output voltage adjustment.  I suspect that the other pins of the pot should go to Vo and GND but who knows!
